# Android Fragment not displayed in React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have followed the RN docs to create an Android Native Fragment:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#1-create-a-fragment

The Fragment is loaded, I can see it in the Layout Inspector, however as you can see in the screenshot, it is in the very bottom of the Views and I'm assuming that's the reason why I can't see the TextView that I have inside of the Fragment.

[image]

So, what does it need to be done do to bring the CustomView to the Front?

I've tried calling: `myFragment.customView.bringToFront();` but didn't work.

The commit() always returns -1:

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .add(reactNativeViewId, myFragment, String.valueOf(reactNativeViewId))
      .commit();
```

I've followed the article, went back and forth into the instructions and everything is there.

I have created a repo to help debug the issue:
https://github.com/wilsolutions/react-native-experiments

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote that part of the documentation. I added the missing parts (and also fixed an issue that caused layout to be unpredictable) in this PR:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/pull/2599. Please let me know if you still miss something.

Answer wrapped up basically:

- CustomView has to extend FrameLayout like in above PR
- in your ViewManager's `setupLayout` method

```java
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(reactNativeViewId).getParent();
```

should be

```java
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(reactNativeViewId);
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you!!!